# Alternative of gnash in 20.04

Tags: gnash

Today updated my laptop from 18.04 to 20.04 LTS, but it is not supporting SWF file. In previous version swf file run bu gnash player, but latest version gnash deleted and not  finding in softwar center. Please tell me how to insnall gnash or inform any alternative of gnash

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/a/1293868/286437

Answer (score 2):

Standalone Flash Player, downloadable from Adobe website: https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html (it's called "Flash Player Projector")