# Build gnash on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, compiling, gstreamer, gnash

To play some old flash animations I need a flash player for ubuntu 20.04. I was used to use [Gnash](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnash/), but this is no longer shipped with ubuntu. So I tried to compile it by myself, i.e. cloned the git repository, did `./autogen.sh`, `./configure` and tried to install all missing libraries. That worked except for:

```
ERROR: GST media handling requested but gstreamer-0.10+ not found
                 Install it from http://www.gstreamer.net
                 or .deb users: apt-get install libgstreamer0.10-dev
                 or .rpm users: yum install gstreamer-devel
                 or yast users: yast install gstreamer010-devel
ERROR: Base plugins are required for gstreamer media!
       Install gstreamer-plugins-base from http://www.gstreamer.net
       or .deb users: apt-get install 
                      libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev
       or .rpm users: yum install gstreamer-plugins-base-devel
ERROR: No xulrunner development package is installed!
       Install it from 
       http://releases.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner
       or .deb users: apt-get install xulrunner-dev
       or maybe     : apt-get install npapi-sdk-dev
       or maybe     : apt-get install firefox-dev
       or .rpm users: yum install xulrunner-devel
       or specify --disable-npapi
```

For the last one I didn't find a `xulrunner-dev` or an `npapi-dev` package in the ubuntu repositories, but installed `firefox-dev`. This didn't work, so I used `--disable-npapi`.

For the `gstreamer` plugins I installed the version 1.0 instead. But if I do `make` I get the following error message:

```
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/myuser/build/gnash'
Making all in desktop
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/myuser/build/gnash/desktop'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/myuser/build/gnash/desktop'
Making all in libdevice
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/myuser/build/gnash/libdevice'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/myuser/build/gnash/libdevice'
Making all in libbase
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/myuser/build/gnash/libbase'
sed -e 's|@DEFAULT_FLASH_PLATFORM_ID[@]|LNX|g' -e 's|@DEFAULT_FLASH_MAJOR_VERSION[@]|10|g' -e 's|@DEFAULT_FLASH_MINOR_VERSION[@]|1|g' -e 's|@DEFAULT_FLASH_REV_NUMBER[@]|999|g' -e 's|@DEFAULT_STREAMS_TIMEOUT[@]|60|g' -e 's|@DEFAULT_SOL_SAFEDIR[@]|~/.gnash/SharedObjects|g'  './gnashrc.in' >gnashrc
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/myuser/build/gnash/libbase'
Making all in libmedia
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/myuser/build/gnash/libmedia'
  CXX      libgnashmedia_la-AudioDecoderGst.lo
In file included from gst/AudioDecoderGst.cpp:20:
gst/AudioDecoderGst.h:27:10: fatal error: gst/gst.h: No such file or directory
   27 | #include <gst/gst.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [Makefile:1126: libgnashmedia_la-AudioDecoderGst.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/myuser/build/gnash/libmedia'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1163: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/myuser/build/gnash'
make: *** [Makefile:1071: all] Error 2
```

So how can I make `gnash` work on ubuntu 20.04.?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/a/1292927/286437

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compilation of Gnash on modern systems like 20.04 LTS is not possible because of changed APIs.

But you can use [schroot](https://wiki.debian.org/Schroot) container with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with Gnash installed inside it as written below:

```
sudo apt-get install schroot debootstrap -y

cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/schroot/chroot.d/bionic.conf
[bionic]
description=Ubuntu 18.04 bionic
directory=/srv/chroot/bionic
root-users=$USER
type=directory
users=$USER
EOF

sudo mkdir -p /srv/chroot/bionic
sudo debootstrap bionic /srv/chroot/bionic

cat <<EOF | sudo tee /srv/chroot/bionic/etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse
EOF

schroot -c bionic -u root apt-get update
schroot -c bionic -u root apt-get install gnash
```

To run it use command below:

```
schroot -c bionic -u $USER env DISPLAY=:0.0 gnash path/to/file.swf
```

Comment: See update above.

Comment: Great answer, works very well.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and most effective way is to download the "Adobe Flash Player Standalone Version" directly from the [official source](https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html)
Scroll down for the Linux 32/64-bit version.

I noticed while searching for the provided link, that Adobe is [terminating](https://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/end-of-life.html#) Flash Player

```
Important Reminder: Flash Player’s end of life is December 31st, 2020. Please see the Flash Player EOL Information page for more details.
```

[image]